# uniform continuity of maximum of slice function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function from $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Define $g : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ as $g(x) = \max\{f(x,y) | y \in [0,1]\}$.

Is this statement true?

> If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ then $g$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.

Thanks.

Comment: $\max\{f(x,y)\mid y\in[0,1]\}$?

Comment: ahh, yes. It was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $[0, 1]$ is compact it suffices to show $g$ is continuous at each point in $[0, 1]$.  Similarly since $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Fix $x \in [0, 1]$ and $\epsilon > 0$.  Then by uniform continuity of $f$, we can pick $\delta > 0$ such that for $||(x, y) - (x', y')|| < \delta$, then $|f(x, y) - f(x', y')| < \epsilon$.  By this continuity of $f$, fix $x \in [0, 1]$.  Then for any $x'$ with $|x - x'| < \delta$, $$|f(x,y) - f(x', y)| < \epsilon,$$ so we see $$|\sup_{y \in [0, 1]} f(x', y) - \sup_{y \in [0, 1]} f(x, y)| < \epsilon,$$ and hence $|g(x) - g(x')| < \epsilon$.

Comment: (+1) To make this just a bit clearer: write
$$
f(x', y) - \epsilon < f(x,y) < f(x', y) + \epsilon
$$
And take the supremum over all $y$ of the above inequality.

Comment: Ah that would be a lot clearer.  I have a sort of picture in my head of a graph that I'm trying to communicate, but that can get lost in translation.  Thanks @Goos.